# Identifying patterns in SQL. Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am attempting to replicate the *Example Output Table* below, but not sure how to proceed. I have tried using the LAG function with limited success

`CASE WHEN LAG(mode, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY Cluster_Name, Node_Name) ORDER BY date 
 != mode 
 THEN date`

It finds the date the mode switched, but I am not sure how to replicate the *Example Output Table*

A cycle starts when the first gas mode/volume is recorded and ends when the last water volume is recorded. Ie: for Foxtrot, only 1 cycle occurs, even though there is a water value on 3/18/2019. This is because no gas cycle occurred prior to that.

**Raw Data**

```
| Cluster_Name | Node_Name | Mode  | volume | date      | *Annotation Only*|
|--------------|-----------|-------|--------|-----------|------------------|         
| Cluster A    | Foxtrot   | water | 100    | 3/18/2019 |                            
| Cluster A    | Foxtrot   | gas   | 200    | 3/19/2019 | Cycle 1                    
| Cluster A    | Foxtrot   | gas   | 200    | 3/20/2019 |                            
| Cluster A    | Foxtrot   | water | 100    | 3/21/2019 |                            
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | water | 820    | 4/29/2018 |                            
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | gas   | 500    | 4/30/2018 | Cycle 1                    
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | gas   | 500    | 5/1/2018  |                            
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | gas   | 500    | 5/2/2018  |                            
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | water | 1,000  | 5/3/2018  |                            
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | water | 1,000  | 5/4/2018  |                            
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | water | 1,000  | 5/5/2018  |                            
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | gas   | 300    | 5/6/2018  | Cycle 2                    
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | gas   | 300    | 5/7/2018  |                            
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | water | 2,000  | 5/8/2018  |                            
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | gas   | 300    | 5/9/2018  | Cycle 3                    
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | water | 2,000  | 5/10/2018 |                            
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | gas   | 1,500  | 5/11/2018 | Cycle 4
```

**Example Output Table**

This table acts as a kind pivot table, aggregating on cluster/node/cycle # by summation of volume.

```
| Cluster_Name | Node_Name | Mode  | Total_Volume | Cycle # |
|--------------|-----------|-------|--------------|---------|
| Cluster A    | Foxtrot   | gas   | 400          | Cycle 1 |
| Cluster A    | Foxtrot   | water | 100          | Cycle 1 |
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | gas   | 1,500        | Cycle 1 |
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | water | 3,000        | Cycle 1 |
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | gas   | 600          | Cycle 2 |
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | water | 2,000        | Cycle 2 |
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | gas   | 300          | Cycle 3 |
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | water | 1,200        | Cycle 3 |
| Cluster B    | Alpha     | gas   | 1,500        | Cycle 4 |
```

Comment: Why does the second line of your expected output have `Cycle1` when the input data doesn't have a value in that column for that row?  Is this a typo, or are there some rules you need to be applied (and what are they)?

Comment: Is this MySQL or Oracle?  (Most deployments of MySQL don't have LAG() yet, it's only in the latest version; 8)

Comment: Will there only ever be two possible values in `Mode`?  Or can there be others?

Comment: @MatBailie There can only be two modes (water or gas) and NULL. This is on Oracle, but will eventually be ported to MySQL. I should have mentioned earlier, that I am starting the cycle count at the beginning of every minimum gas date of gas value. Once it has gone from gas - water and back to gas, it has completed 1 full cycle.

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that you're using Oracle or MySQL 8 *(assumed because you said you're trying to use `LAG()`, and older version of MySQL don't have `LAG()`)

Also assumes, there are only two modes, and that you never want any of the readings from the first mode.

```
WITH
    sorted_data AS
(
    SELECT
        rawdata.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cluster_name, node_name
                               ORDER BY date
                          )
                             AS node_seq_num,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cluster_name, node_name, mode
                               ORDER BY date
                          )
                             AS node_mode_seq_num
    FROM
        your_data
),
   aggregated_data AS
(
    SELECT
        cluster_name,
        node_name,
        mode,
        MIN(date)   AS first_date,
        MAX(date)   AS final_date,
        SUM(volume) AS total_volume,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cluster_name, node_name, mode, node_seq_num - node_mode_seq_num
                               ORDER BY node_seq_num - node_mode_seq_num
                          )
                             AS node_mode_group_seq_num
    FROM
        sorted_data
    GROUP BY
        cluster_name,
        node_name,
        mode,
        node_seq_num - node_mode_seq_num
)
SELECT
    *,
   node_mode_group_seq_num / 2   AS cycle_num
FROM
    aggregated_data
WHERE
    node_mode_group_seq_num > 1
ORDER BY
    cluster_name,
    node_name,
    mode,
    node_mode_group_seq_num
```

*(In MySQL you'll need `TRUNC(node_mode_group_seq_num / 2)`)*

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `lag()`, as in:

```
select rd.*
from (select rd.*,
             lag(mode) over (partition by cluster_name, mode_name order by date) as prev_mode
      from rawdata rd
     ) rd
where prev_mode <> mode;
```

Normally, when doing this, I would want the first record as well.  That would be:

```
where prev_mode is null or prev_mode <> mode
```

Comment: Looking at the OP's required output, the `total_volume` column appears to be an aggregate of the input data.  *(It wasn't described, which doesn't help)*